# Replacing a column values with another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame of 6 columns that 2 first columns should be plotted as x & y. I want to replace the values of the 6th column with other values and then excluding x, y that have values larger than a threshold like 0.0003-0.002. The effort that I had is below:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('configuration_1000.out', sep="\s+", header=None)

#print(df)

col_5 = df.iloc[:,5]

g = col_5.abs()

g = g*0.00005

#print(g)

df.loc[:,5].replace(g, inplace=True)

#df.head()

selected = df[ (df.loc[:,5] > 0.0003) & (df.loc[:,5] < 0.002) ]

print(selected)

plt.plot(selected[0], selected[1],marker=".")
```

but when I do this, nothing is gonna changed.

Comment: Instead of replace try `df.loc[:,5] = g`

Comment: @techytushar thanks, I posted the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need iloc for this, nor do you need to go through the intermediate steps. Just manipulate the column directly.

```
df[df.columns[5]] = abs(df[df.columns[5]])*0.00005
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem just need to do this

```
df.loc[:,5] = g
```